# Using closures or the underscore convention for private members

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Douglas Crockford and many others [suggest using closures for private members](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) as follows:

```
function Container(param) {

    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

The upside of this is that these members are not accessible outside the constructor function, but the downside is that it's not possible to use the private members in the prototype. So you end up putting everything that uses the private members in the constructor, which is not good for memory purposes.

Some others recommend using underscores when naming the private members:

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
    this._secret = 3;
}

Container.prototype.dec = function {
    if (this.secret > 0) {
        this.secret -= 1;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The downside of this is that those members are easily accessible publicly, and the only thing stopping people is the convention.

My questions are:

1. When do you decide to use one over the other?
2. Is one way preferred more commonly than the other?
3. What are some famous libraries that use one of these methods?
4. Is there a better method than these two?

Comment: 1.  Generally when the benefits outweigh the downsides. 2. is subjective IMO. 3. is off topic. 4. Maybe the use of WeakMaps or Symbols.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the sarcasm that adds absolutely no value.

Comment: I wasn't sarcastic. The benefits of using either of these methods very much depend on your concrete use cases of these classes (which we don't know about).

Comment: @FelixKling I don't mean to be rude but "when the benefits outweigh the downsides" is a non-answer. When do you think benefits outweigh the downsides? And for the second one, how can something that can be quantified be subjective? And thanks for the rest of your comment.

Comment: *"When do you think benefits outweigh the downsides?"* When there is a real possibility that people would access "private members" and/or these members contain computed data that you have to prevent people getting access to. If you just want to prevent people from messing with the internal state of the component, I wouldn't bother. Let them shoot themselves in the foot if they want to. Preventing this is not worth the additional complexity. However, this is more (my) opinion than anything else.

Comment: @FelixKling That's a good point, thanks.

Comment: "*which is not good for memory purposes*" **[citation needed]**, please

Comment: @Bergi this way what happens is every time you create an instance of that object, the methods will be inside the instance. But if you create them in the prototype, these methods will be shared by all the instances, without actually including them.

Comment: @FelixKling: It's also a very popular opinion :-)

Comment: @hattenn: I know what happens. I do however claim that it doesn't make much difference in regards to memory. Especially when you don't instantiate myriads of objects (which in general you do not).

Comment: @Bergi, probably not in most cases. But it's just obvious that having them in the prototype is better in terms of memory, even if it's trivial in many cases. Other than my answer, and maybe a citation to ES, I don't think it needs citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already outlined, there are tradeoffs between these two methods.  So, which to use depends entirely upon the specifics of your use cases and there is no answer that doesn't consider the actual use cases.  You can bound the decision a few ways:

If you are making **tens of thousands of these objects**, then perhaps the increased memory usage of not using the prototype is meaningful and you might want to sacrifice true privacy in order to manage your memory usage and use the prototype version that doesn't have real privacy.  If you're not making large numbers of objects **or running in a very compact memory footprint**, the memory usage difference is unlikley  to matter.

Crockford makes a case that the memory issue is rarely a real issue these days.  But, I think that's just a general statement and you have to evaluate your particular situation to know whether that's true or not.

If **privacy is paramount** and you absolutely don't want outsiders mucking with internal private variables (perhaps it's even a security thing from an API or a reliability issue), then by all means choose the closure option that gives you real privacy.

> When do you decide to use one over the other?

It depends upon what you most want to optimize for and the best choice is specific to the use case.

> Is one way preferred more commonly than the other?

It depends upon what you most want to optimize for and the best choice is specific to the use case.

> What are some famous libraries that use one of these methods?

jQuery uses a mixture of these.  It has some "non-public" properties that start with an underscore.  And, it uses some closure variables that are truly private, though generally only for objects of which there are only one or a small number of or sometimes just for module-level globals.  Over time, it appears to me that jQuery has switched some of its `_priv` properties to more protected closure variables, but still has some of each.

This is likely because jQuery is trying to optimize memory use for a jQuery object itself and thus doesn't want to create an extra closure or use extra memory for methods.  But, for other types of objects it uses where there are not so many, it can more easily afford the extra memory usage for true privacy.

> Is there a better method than these two?

If you have weakMaps available, there is another option.  Closures are the best scheme I've seen for true privacy that works across even older browsers.  The only other means of indicating non-public is by convention and the leading underscore is the more common convention for doing so.

---

Per Felix's suggestion, here's how the `weakMap` option works.

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    var data = new WeakMap();
    return class MyClass {
        constructor() {
            var secretData = {
                foo: 42
            };
            data.set(this, secretData);
        }
        // normal prototyped method can get access to the private data
        doSomethingWithSecret() {
            return data.get(this).foo * 2;
        }
    };
}());
```

There's one `WeakMap` object per class definition.  In the constructor of your object you use `this` as a key to store an object in the weakMap.  Since you need both `this` and access to the `weakMap` in order to get access to the private data, only methods defined within the private closure will have access to the weakMap, but unlike the Crockford method, you can use .prototype methods in this closure.  This creates one closure per class and one `WeakMap` object per class so neither of those are per instance.

Since everything here seems to be some sort of tradeoff, there's a little performance hit every time you want to get or set data to the WeakMap vs. either of the other two approaches.  How much of a performance hit would depend entirely upon the weakMap implementation and would have to be measured if performance was paramount, but it's likely a bit more of a lookup process than just a plain property lookup and perhaps not as optimized since its a relatively new feature too.

Comment: `WeakMap`s can also be used to store private instance data, but of course that only works in environments that support it and one needs to prevent access to the map (which is easy to achieve). It has none of the disadvantage the other two approaches have.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yeah, weakMaps have interesting uses when available.  But, to solve this particular problem, you either have to put the weakMap somewhere private (still same issue) or you have to have a private and unknown key to access the private data elements.  If this is per-instance data, you still have to find a per-instance place to store something private.

Comment: Hiding the map is easy with closures. All instances have access to the same map. Simple example: `var MyClass = (function() { var data = new WeakMap(); return class MyClass { constructor() { var secretData = {foo: 42}; data.set(this, secretData); } doSomethingWithSecret() { return data.get(this).foo * 2; } }; }());`

Comment: @FelixKling - I incorporated your suggestion into my answer.  Thx.